# How to match array objects with regex in this example?

Tags: javascript

So I have an array filled with strings that look like the following:

```
obj-meta_version-11_info
obj-meta_version-12_info
obj-meta_version-13_info
```

I want to loop through that array and identify objects that follow this naming convention.  I believe the regex would look something like this:

```
obj-meta_version-([\d .]+)_info
```

Here is full example of what I am trying to do:

```
    for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
      if body[i].name = obj-meta_version-([\d .]+)_info {
         // do stuff
      }
    }
```

How do I rewrite this if statement in js to properly use the regex?  I'm coming from python background so not sure how to do this.

Comment: You could start by reading [an introductory tutorial on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Try `if(body[i].name.match(/your-regex/))...`

Comment: `if (` **operand** `==` **operand** `) {` **...** or `===` operator at the very least. And all string are wrapped in a pair of single or double quotes -- or a pair of backticks: `'` or `"` or ```

Comment: Oh and most importantly don't use RegEx to compare simple strings, it's like cleaning your dishes with a toothbrush. `.includes()` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your could would look like this:

```js
const body = [
  {name:'obj-meta_version-11_info'},
  {name:'wrong'},
  {name:'obj-meta_version-12_info'},
  {name:'obj-meta_version-13_info'},
  {name:'wrong again'},
];

for(let i=0; i<body.length; i++){
  if (body[i].name.match(/obj-meta_version-([\d .]+)_info/)) {
      console.log(body[i]);
  }
}
```

And here is sample output:

```
{ name: 'obj-meta_version-11_info' }
{ name: 'obj-meta_version-12_info' }
{ name: 'obj-meta_version-13_info' }
```

Changes:

1. added `(` and `)` to condition in `if`
2. wrapped regexp into pair of `/` -- this is regexp literal, it consutrcts RegExp object which can be used to match strings against patterns
3. actually applied regexp to name field of each object

Note: I'm not sure about `[\d .]` part, which means "one digit 0-9, or a space character, or a dot -- is it really what you wanted there? Seems more like `\d+`, i.e. one or more digits.